# Do foreign acronyms take a definite article, and of which gender?

Tags: estrangeirismos, gênero

For example is NASA simply "NASA" or "a NASA" or "o NASA"?

What rule(s) determine the answer? The gender of the principal word in the acronym ("agency"/"agência" in this example)?  The natural gender of the "word" (e.g. "nasa" would appear feminine), or something else?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, they do. Its gender is determined by the main noun.

**Examples**

- NASA is an agency (*agência*, f.) → ***a*** NASA
- RAM is a memory (*memória*, f.) → ***a*** RAM
- NATO is an organization (*organização*, f.) → ***a*** NATO or ***a*** OTAN (Organização do Tratado do Atlântico Norte)
- IMF is a fund (*fundo*, m.) → ***o*** IMF or ***o*** FMI (Fundo Monetário Internacional)
- TGV is a train (*comboio*, m. / *trem*, m.) → ***o*** TGV (Train à grande vitesse)

*Added*.

- Sometimes the noun is implicit as in "the MI5 (Service)" → ***o*** (Serviço) MI5.
- The same rule applies to Portuguese acronyms like *o IST*, which stands for *Instituto Superior Técnico*, where *instituto* is a masculine noun.

Comment: We talk "a OTAN" :)

Comment: @bigown I've edited the answer.

Comment: @bigown In Portugal we use NATO more, but OTAN is also used.

Comment: Your answer is solid, but it does not address cases such as "o FBI" (**a** Agência Federal de Investigação), as @someonewithapc raised in his question.

Comment: @ANeves "o FBI" é sem dúvida uma agência, mas na sigla o substantivo principal é "bureau", no sentido de "departamento (governamental)", daí o artigo definido masculino; por oposição "a CIA", cujo substantivo é "agency".

Comment: Acrescentaria ainda que por vezes o genéro parece mudar consoante o contexto. Por exemplo, para referir o website/motor de busca, oiço consistententemente *o Google*, mas para referir a empresa, *a Google* é talvez mais comum.

Comment: @Artefacto Certo, porém o exemplo que dá não é um acrónimo,  mas um substantivo comum.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they do. Generaly the same rules used to determine the gender of a word in Portuguese are applied; an example of these rules is checking wheter the word ends in *a* or in *o*. For instance, it seems natural to me to say *a* NASA, *a* NSA, but not *a* FBI and rather *o* FBI.

However, there are no fixed rules on which to use, so you'll just use which ever sounds better.

Answer (score -2):

Acronyms are written just like they were written in words.

> Os Estados Unidos da America. Os EUA.
>
> O Reino Unido. O RU.

Foreign acronyms are no different, the only problem is determining the gender of the foreign word.

Most times it takes the gender of the most common Portuguese translation.